# Limit in Polar Coordinates?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

**EDIT:** this is wrong, in fact the limit does not exist, as indicated in the answers.

Consider the following limit:
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2}{x + y^2}.
$$

It is easy to show, without using polar coordinates, that such a limit is $0$. Indeed,
$$
0 \leq\Bigg|\frac{x^2}{x + y^2}\Bigg| = \Bigg|\frac{x}{x + y^2}\Bigg||x| \leq |x|,
$$
and the argument follows by the squeeze theorem. Now assume that we do not know this fact and we start using polar coordinates instead. Write
$$
x = r\cos(\theta), y = r \sin(\theta).
$$
Then,
$$
\frac{x^2}{x + y^2} = \frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{\frac{\cos(\theta)}{r} + \sin^{2}(\theta)}.
$$
It is obvious that, for a fixed $\theta$, the above expression goes to zero as $r \to 0$, but of course, this is not enough to show what we want. What we have to see is that there exists a one-variable function $h = h(r)$, *depending **only** on $r$*, such that
$$
0 \leq \Bigg|\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{\frac{\cos(\theta)}{r} + \sin^{2}(\theta)}\Bigg| \leq h(r)
$$
for every $\theta$ and $r$, and with $\lim_{r \to 0}h(r) = 0$.

**The question is:** how do we find the function $h = h(r)$ in our case?

**EDIT:** this is wrong, in fact the limit does not exist, as indicated in the answers.

Comment: What about $|r\cos\theta|$ ? :-)

Comment: Clearly, $x+y^2=0$ is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is **NOT** zero. It does not exist!

If $x=y^2$, as $y\to 0$, then $x\to 0$ and
$$\frac{x^2}{x + y^2}
=\frac{y^4}{y^2 + y^2}=y^2\to 0.$$
On the other hand, along the curve $x=-y^2+y^4$, as $y\to 0$, then $x\to 0$ and
$$\frac{x^2}{x + y^2}
=\frac{(-y^2+y^4)^2}{-y^2+y^4 + y^2}=\frac{y^4-2y^6+y^8}{y^4}=
1-2y^2+y^4\to 1.$$
Indeed, in your first approach, $\left|\frac{x}{x + y^2}\right|$ is NOT bounded in a neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: Yes you are right, the limit does not exist!

Comment: Yes, it does not exists.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake and thank you!

Comment: @Smm You are welcome!

Comment: This makes me wonder another thing: in a previous answer, which was deleted, it was suggested to use $x=r^2\cos^2(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, or something like that. Can we use polar coordinates with $x=r^a\cos^{b}(\theta)$ and $x=r^c\sin^{d}(\theta)$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$? I guess that the answer is no, otherwise we would get a contradiction with this limit, since it does not exist...

Comment: But the thing is that, if I am not wrong, using this substitution, our expression reduces to $r^2\cos^{4}(\theta)$, therefore the limit would be zero, which is false.

Comment: No, $x=r^2\cos^2(\theta)\geq0$ therefore you are restricting the domain.

Comment: Ok, therefore we cannot use this in order to deduce the existence and value of the limit, I thought you said it was possible. Thanks! But if the exponents are odd, then, can we?

Comment: Try https://www.monroecc.edu/faculty/paulseeburger/calcnsf/CalcPlot3D/
and consider the graph of the function in the halfplane $x<0$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read carefully your substitution.

Comment: Cant we use $x=\pm r^2 \cos^2 \theta$ Robert ?

Comment: @Aryadeva I am not sure of your approach. Why do you want to use these substitution?

Comment: Not here just asking the question in general. Here it won't help Robert.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have an answer that works in general.